How to close the hole smoothly convex?
Good afternoon. Is it possible to close the hole with a quick click so that it is convex, as it were, an extension of the model? As in the red lines. Or is the only way out - Filling by F and pulling polygons manually?


Hello, I would boolean with an object that has the shape you want, then use a Smooth brush to hide the junction
